# Load jQuery 3 for one script only, then revert to 1?

Tags: jquery, updates

I've got an issue with jQuery.

Since WordPress "refuses" to update the jQuery 1, and I need a higher one to run a simple script containing the function `$.trim`, is there anyway to just load jQuery 3 for just that script, and then revert to jQuery 1?

I tried the plug-in that "updates" the jQuery, but then did bootstrap complain that it can't run on jQuery 3 and above..

As you so might realise with this question, I'm a newbie regarding jQuery and JavaScript..  so is there any "***temp load new jQuery and unload it after script finished***" way?

Edit: the following error is displayed in the console:

```
(index):1599 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
    at HTMLOptionElement.<anonymous> ((index):1599)
    at jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2
    at Function.grep (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at z (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at a.fn.init.filter (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at (index):1599
```

This is the short jQuery I'm trying g to run:

```
jQuery('select option').filter(function() { return !this.value || $.trim(this.value).length == 0 || $.trim(this.text).length == 0; }).remove();
```

Comment: `trim` is available in jQuery 1, according to [this](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/), and there's also an equivalent function in normal JS, so you don't even need jQuery. What's the actual issue you're experiencing?

Comment: The issue is that it's not working unless I run the jQuery 3, I've updated the question with the error code I see in the console

Comment: Yes, that solved it, which is strange, because I tried that before posting here, but now it's working...